# Memory not deallocated - PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, garbage-collection, pyqt4

It might be the bindings (SIP) or even python, but I have a problem with Qt (pyqt4).

I have a QTabWidget, and inside it I put widgets one can close.

I have a widget that allocates about 400mb of memory. I have not set a parent, and I call `deleteLater()` on close but nothing happens. Even calling the python's gc does not work:

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

Now when closing the widgets from the QTabWidget without using `deleteLater()` more and more memory is allocated. So lets say I open up 4 tabs of the memory-heavy widget, I use around 1.6GB memory. If I close them all, and open a new, I am now up to 2GB of memory usage.

If I use the `deleteLater()`, after closing the 4 tabs, I do not go up to 2GB opening a new one, then I have to open 5 tabs. But, and here is the **problem**, 1.6GB is still allocated for the process (python) even tho all widgets are closed, and `deleteLater` has been called.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this - somewhere you have an reference to your widget, and that reference has been counted... the only way to delete that widget is to make sure that there are no remaining references so python can garbage-collect it.

At least you don't end up with a dangling reference like C++, which can lead to some nasty crashes...

---

This can actually be useful - if you create a class with a class-level list of its members, you can recycle old objects and never have them garbage-collected

Comment: Well how come I can use deleteLater() so that when I close the tabs, I dont allocate more when opening new ones. I think thats strange, that the the memory allocation is being held on 1.6GB when I can "replace" it with new widgets (tabs). Why not deallocate when you can "replace"?

Comment: @Johannes : deleteLayer does not remove any references other than those internal to PyQt's handling of the layer. Look for your missing references. They're there or you've found a bug in PyQt. Them being there is far more likely. I lost a day to this problem, but it taught me to be more careful with my namespaces...

Comment: Can it be that the widget, had references to some objects that was referenced from other parts of the program? Because the widget, is not referenced any other place, but it's components and "data" might be.

Comment: Yes, this could be it, there are a fair few 'quirks' in PyQt relating to the way C++ does things, that are not the same as the way python does them. It is entirely possible that one of its 'components' or some of its 'data' references it, stopping it from being garbage collected. If I know more about your widget I might be able to point you in the right direction; however I'd understand if it was sensitive.

Comment: It was a "circular ref problem" as you stated. But fixing it is more complicated than spotting the error. Now I know at least what's causing it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah it's ok - as I said - this has happened to me once and I lost a day to spotting it and fixing it in a personal project I'd only spent a few hundred hours on... Hopefully it won't cause you too much grief, but I'll tell you what - I learnt my lesson, and it's stopped me from producing similar code in other circumstances - hopefully increasing my standard of code...